# Paypal Braintree pop blocked in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, braintree

Paypal Braintree pop up blocked in chrome asking permissions when called from onReady method.

Below is braintree.setup onready function

```
    onReady: function(integration) {
      console.log('Braintree is ready');
      checkout = integration;
      enablePaypalBtn();
    }
```

Below is the button code

```
    <button id="my-button-element" style="visibility:none"></button>
    var checkout;
    document.querySelector('#my-button-element').addEventListener('click', 
    function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      checkout.paypal.initAuthFlow();
    }, false);
```

Whereas if I call directly my-button-element click event from console pop is shown without asking permission.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Per [Braintree's docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration#setup-method-options), `initAuthFlow` must be called synchronously as result of a user click event or the PayPal flow popup will automatically be blocked by the browser. You need to tie `enablePaypalBtn()` to a user click action.

Also, wanted to mention Braintree has a newer Javascript library, [v3](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/). If you can, I recommend [migrating to the newest version](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/migration/javascript/v3).